# Customize FileSavePicker UI?

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp, customization, filesavepicker

In an Windows Forms app you can customize **SaveFileDialog** with checkboxes and buttons etc[image: Customized Windows Forms SaveFileDialog]

How can I do the same with the **FileSavePicker** in an UWP app? Is there any way to add custom UI controls to the FileSavePicker dialog?

Comment: No, customizing FileSavePicker is not currently possible.  Don't hold your breath for it.

Answer (score 2):

FilePicker does have some options to add file type filters and customize its options : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker

but it does not provide a way to actually change its UI o some deep customization, but if you really want this feature in a future SDK you can request for it on uservoice : https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform